# How do I get my app icon to show in the bottom left corner of the lock screen and have it link to the app store?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

How to place my  app icon on the lock screen when app is  not  installed in devices and is  there any way to connect App Store apps that apps  will display  on the  lock screen bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't do nothing. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26676020/2139186):

Especially:

`(...) and there is no mechanism or process by which an App developer can add their App to the list of recommended Apps. (...)`