# How can I have an iBeacon advertise my app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I've noticed when going to different places that iOS is reacting to iBeacons by advertising the business associated app (like Apple's App Store app when going into an App Store). This advertisement is presented in the lock screen's bottom left corner.
How is this implemented? Does the app need to be installed, or can it be advertised so the user can download it?
(See this as well: [Make app appear as iOS 8 Suggested App at lockscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082414/make-app-appear-as-ios-8-suggested-app-at-lockscreen))

Comment: http://blog.estimote.com/post/97824495825/ios-8-pushes-location-context-to-a-new-level-lock

Comment: This is good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082414/make-app-appear-as-ios-8-suggested-app-at-lockscreen