# Why some app icon can be displayed on lock screen

Tags: ios

I found that one of my app's icon can be displayed on locked screen. How to implement this by programming.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make app appear as iOS 8 Suggested App at lockscreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082414/make-app-appear-as-ios-8-suggested-app-at-lockscreen)

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the [feature handoff](https://developer.apple.com/handoff/).

> Handoff lets users start an activity on one device and seamlessly resume the activity on another device. Provide continuity for users with multiple devices by supporting Handoff in your apps and websites