# iOS 8 Suggested App icon lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

iOS Suggested App feature will show app icon on left bottom corner in iPhone lock screen.

Which delegate method will be called (on UIApplication or I don't know) 
when clicking on the bottom left app icon ?

[image]

Comment: What? Could you please rephrase your question? I have no idea what you are asking. Are you talking about Handoff?

Comment: @dasdom : i have edit my question with image, ios 8 will app icon in lock screen, once you click on that it will open your app on that time which delegate method it will called that i want to know.

Answer (score 3):

The **Suggested Apps** feature is a list of apps that are popular/relevant to specific locations, managed entirely by Apple.One can request to be added to that list for a specific app.
You can read more about it in this answer to a similar question, where an Apple Tech Support explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26676020/2242359
Sliding up the icon from there will either open the AppStore page of the app or simply launch the app.

The other way to get you app icon to the corner of the lock screen is by using iBeacon - in that way the app must already be installed on the users device and the icon will appear when getting close to the iBeacon device.

Comment: Thanks @Aviel Gross for quick answer, so it will called the appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method if my app is not in background ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. To get the iBeacon monitoring to work though, you have to set region monitoring within your app, and to get the user's permission to "always receive location data, even when not using the app". This will allow the functionality of the iPhone to find the iBeacon even when the app is terminated